Why does characteristic equation and DC model equation for drain current in JFETs do not agree?
I am reading Semiconductor Devices — Theory and Application (Fiore) about JFETs in chapter 10 and there are two drain current equations shown that do not agree with each other.
The first equation is the standard characteristic equation of a JFET drain current:
$$I_D = I_{DSS}\left(1 - \frac{V_{GS}}{V_{GS(off)}}\right)^2$$
and the second equation is shown in the DC model of a JFET:

which is:
$$I_D = g_mV_{GS}$$
Now given example 10.4.1 from the book as shown in the image:

for \$I_{DSS} = 10\;\mathrm{mA}\$, \$V_{GS(off)} = -5\;\mathrm V\$ and \$V_{GS}=-2\;\mathrm V\$  we can calculate drain current with the first equation as:
$$I_D = 10\;\mathrm{mA}\left(1-\frac{-2\;\mathrm V}{-5\;\mathrm V}\right)^2=3.6\;\mathrm{mA}$$
while using the second equation, we get:
$$I_D = g_{m0}\left(1-\frac{V_{GS}}{V_{GS(off)}}\right)V_{GS}$$
where:
$$g_{m0} = -\frac{2I_{DSS}}{V_{GS(off)}}$$
which gives us:
$$I_D = -\frac{2\cdot 10\;\mathrm{mA}}{-5\;\mathrm V}\left(1 - \frac{-2\;\mathrm V}{-5\;\mathrm V}\right)(-2\;\mathrm V) = 4.8\;\mathrm{mA}$$
So am I misunderstanding something in regards to the model, or is the model just a really bad approximation?

That's not a great DC model; it completely ignores that the gate junction is a diode.

@Hearth yes the gate junction is a reverse biased diode but I don't see how adding that fact to the model would improve the accuracy in relation to drain current.

My point is that I would consider that a small-signal AC model, not a DC model.

Wrong, the second equation id = gm*vgs is a small-sign an AC model only, not a DC one.  Thus, they are not equivalent.

The second equation is the small signal model of a transconductance (e.g. a transistor operating in it's transconductance regime). The equation characterizes how much the drain current varies around it's DC operating point for a small change in the gate-source voltage.
The way the two equations are related is via the first order Taylor series approximation. If you compute
$$ i_d = \frac{\partial I_D}{\partial V_{GS}} v_{gs} $$
Where \$\frac{\partial I_D}{\partial V_{GS}}\ = g_m \$ evaluated at some DC bias point.
Now it's very important to note that this small signal model only applies for small changes in \$v_{gs}\$ around the DC operating point. In your case, you are abusing the second equation to compute the DC operating point of the amplifier, which is an invalid use case. I.e. for the equation to be valid, we must be able to ignore the higher order terms of the Taylor series.

The model in the book was designated under chapter 10.4.1 called "DC model". Would you say that the model should be designated as an AC model or maybe the drain current equation in the model should be exchanged with the original characteristic equation?

The "DC model" is the large signal model of a JFET in it's square law region (it is not valid for all operating points though). It is valid for AC signals, provided you solve the equation for every individual time point separately. The "AC model" is a small signal model, which is valid for small variations in voltage/current. The changes don't have to be "AC" in the sense that you could have a small DC Vgs change and use the equation to find the small Id change. All of this is just a manifestation of the first order Taylor series approximation.

Let's start with the non-linear large-signal model that you document (which lacks the Early Effect modifier) and take its partial derivative:
$$\begin{align*}
I_{_\text{D}}&=I_{_\text{DSS}}\left(1-\frac{V_{_\text{GS}}}{V_{_\text{GS off}}}\right)^2
\\\\
\partial I_{_\text{D}}&=-2\frac{I_{_\text{DSS}}}{V_{_\text{GS off}}}\left(1-\frac{V_{_\text{GS}}}{V_{_\text{GS off}}}\right)\partial V_{_\text{GS}}
\\\\
&\text{now introduce the idea of }g_{m0}=-2\frac{I_{_\text{DSS}}}{V_{_\text{GS off}}}:
\\\\
\partial I_{_\text{D}}&=g_{m0}\left(1-\frac{V_{_\text{GS}}}{V_{_\text{GS off}}}\right)\partial V_{_\text{GS}}
\end{align*}$$
Please note this is not: \$I_{_\text{D}}=g_{m0}\left(1-\frac{V_{_\text{GS}}}{V_{_\text{GS off}}}\right) V_{_\text{GS}}\$. This mistaken idea is entirely your own error. The partials are infinitely small step variables. Not finite value variables! All that this says is that \$\partial I_{_\text{D}}\$ is proportional to \$\partial V_{_\text{GS}}\$ by a factor of \$k=g_{m0}\left(1-\frac{V_{_\text{GS}}}{V_{_\text{GS off}}}\right)\$.
Everything else from there fails due to unsound reasoning.
(Anytime you see \$g_m\$ you should think "AC small signal" or "differential slope/tangent of a non-linear curve at some specific DC operating point" in your head. \$g_m\$ cannot even be computed without first knowing the DC operating point. The DC operating point must be computed in other ways.)

Thank you for the explanation. Given the tone of your answer being eager to pronounce someone's errors I suggest that you write a peer review on the book, considering this is not my error but the book's only.
You will find concrete proof in chapter 10.4.1 titled as "DC Model" where the equation for small signal analysis is used. Furthermore you will find additional proof in chapter 10.4.2 beginning with the sentence: "Given the transconductance $g_m$, we can find $I_D$." clearly mentioned in regards to DC analysis, considering the topic of JFET biasing.

I don't think you understood me clearly. When I thanked you for your explanation, I meant that I clearly understood it and it made perfect sense to me. I did not try to challenge your answer in any way because I completely agree with it as well.

I don't understand why you are trying to get argumentative with me. I only suggested that you can send your answer as a peer review to the book because obviously the author made a mistake. It is an open source free book, therefore I thought of it as a contribution to the community just like you did with your answer. In the near future my kind advice to you, when writing an answer, is that it contains as much respect towards the interlocutor as it contains well explained information. Otherwise people might appreciate the information but not accept the answer because of ill mannered attitude.

@PhillDonn I'm just being direct in writing. I was discussing your error in analysis as shown in your question. The only thing that matters to me is that what I write helps you.
